# How to get parse notification from parse.com on android device?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Not working app. How get parse data from push notification ?

I sent notification without alert to android device.

```
    ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo(\"device_id\", \"1234567890\"); // device_id created in parse.com
    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setQuery(query);
    push.setData(data);      
    push.sendInBackground(); // i see this notification in parse.com
```

and then i write:

```
public MyCustomReceiver myReceiver = new MyCustomReceiver();
myReceiver.onReceive(this, getIntent());
```

Class for Receive:

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = \"MyCustomReceiver\";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String channel = intent.getExtras().getString(\"org.xxx.xxx.Channel\");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("org.xxx.xxx.Data"));

        Log.d(TAG, \"got action \" + action + \" on channel \" + channel + \" with:\");
        Iterator itr = json.keys();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
            tv_n.setText(json.getString(key));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.xxx.MyCustomReceiver" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.xxx.UPDATE_STATUS" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you "Allow send push from client" on parse.com in settings of your project in Push tab?

did you add your custom receiver to manifest?:

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver
    android:name="YOURPACKAJE.MyCustomReceiver "//its your this class should  extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver 
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver
    android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <category android:name="YOURPACKAJE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

also for more info see this question and my answer [Getting Parse Push Notification in List view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337938/getting-parse-push-notification-in-list-view/32339426#32339426)