# Getting Parse Push Notification in List view

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using parse push notification for my app , the notification comes fine but on clicking the notification I need to show them in a list view , I searched for tutorials but I could not find any . Please help me . Please explain with code , I am new to android . Thanks in advance.
here is my custom receiver.

```
      public class CustomReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

      NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
      Intent resultIntent;
  int mNotificationId = 001;
   Uri notifySound;
   String alert;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try{
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
        alert = json.getString("alert").toString();
    }catch (JSONException e){

    }
    mBuilder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(alert));
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.syncytium);
    mBuilder.setContentText(alert);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Syncytium");
    mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    resultIntent = new Intent(context, com.omc.sunny.syncytium.syncytium.Notification.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId,mBuilder.build());
}
  }
```

here is my Notification class

```
   public class Notification extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView notifTv;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
    notifTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notif);

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String message = getIntent().getExtras().getString("alert");
    notifTv.setText(message);
}

 }
```

Comment: I haven't used parse sdk ever (always implemented my own implementation), but the essence should be same. While sending notification you set a pending intent. You can update the content of the list when the pending intent is executed. Then you can use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or something like that to update the data  shown in the list view.

Answer (score 1):

At first add this to your manifest

```
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="YOURPACKAJE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="YOURPACKAJE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

add it to application tag

```
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="YOURPACKAJE.notifications.MyReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="YOURPACKAJE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

then create class in packaje `YOURPACKAJE.notifications.MyReceiver`

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;


public class MyReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    protected void onPushReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {

        Log.e("ParsePush", "RECIVED");
        if (intent.hasExtra("com.parse.Data")){
            String jsonString=intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data");

            Log.e("", "json " + jsonString);

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                String title= json.getString("title");
                String message= json.getString("message");
    // then call your method to create manually your custom notification with pending intent
//in intent putExtra("title",title), putExtra("message",message)
//and the after opening in Activity catch this intent
                 }
             }
        }
```

in wersite parse.com send notification like JSON

```
{"title":"your tittle is here","message":"your message"}
```

Comment: I did this,how to catch the intent in another activity

Comment: Override method onNewIntent(){getIntent.getExtra("yuorstring");}

Answer (score 0):

dont use `getIntent()`   , use `intent` in method:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("alert");
        notifTv.setText(message);
    }
```